# Why does my slider editor not work in Vaadin 8 grid?

Tags: java, datagrid, kotlin, vaadin, vaadin8

I want to create a Vaadin 8 grid in which I can edit the value in the column `Amount (2)` using a slider (analogous to [this example](http://vasa.demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/item-editor)).

[image: Grid]

I use the following code to create the grid.

```
fun createGrid(): Grid<Concept> {
    val grid = Grid<Concept>()
    val dataProvider = ListDataProvider<Concept>(ctl.getConcepts())
    grid.dataProvider = dataProvider
    grid.addColumn(Concept::getName)
            .setId("ID")
            .setCaption("ID")
    grid.addColumn(Concept::getDescription)
            .setId("desc")
            .setCaption("Description")
    grid.addColumn(Concept::getOutput)
            .setId("amountNumber")
            .setCaption("Amount")

    val conceptAmountditor = Slider()
    conceptAmountditor.setWidth(100.0f, Sizeable.Unit.PERCENTAGE)
    conceptAmountditor.min = 0.0
    conceptAmountditor.max = 100.0

    grid.addColumn(Concept::getOutput, ProgressBarRenderer())
            .setId("amountBar")
            .setCaption("Amount (2)")
            .setEditorComponent(
                    conceptAmountditor,
                    Concept::setOutput
            )
            .setEditable(true)


    grid.setSizeFull()
    return grid
}
```

But when I click on the individual rows, no slider appears.

What is wrong with my code? How can I make the progress bar transform into a slider when I double click a particular row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
    val amount2Col = grid.addColumn(Concept::getOutput, amount2ColRenderer)
            .setId("amountBar")
            .setCaption("Amount (2)")
    val binder = grid.editor.binder
    val amount2ColSlider = Slider()
    val amount2Binding: Binder.Binding<Concept, Double> = binder.bind(
            amount2ColSlider, Concept::getOutput, Concept::setOutput
    )
    amount2Col.setEditorBinding(amount2Binding)
    amount2Col.setEditable(true)
    grid.editor.setEnabled(true)
```

For details see section "Editing Items Inside Grid" on [this page](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-grid.html).